How to alias `reload!` in rails 7.2 console?
I had an alias for reload! command in the rails console:
# ~/.irbrc

if defined? Rails
  def r
    reload!
  end
end

In rails v7.2 this no longer works:
>> r
(stackoverflow):1:in `<main>': undefined method `reload!' for main (NoMethodError)

    reload!
    ^^^^^^^

but reload! still works on its own:
>> reload!
Reloading...

How do I aslias reload! with r?

The future proof way seems to be IRB extensions.
IRB::Command.register(:r, Rails::Console::Reloader)

The entire console integration was changed in Rails 7.2 and a lot of the exisiting functionality moved into rails/railties/lib/rails/commands/console
/irb_console.rb.

Interestingly there is no mention of this in the change notes for 7.2.

thank you, that works. i wonder why they had to make it an IRB::Command instead of IRB::HelperMethod which would make reload! a regular ruby method.

"If you don't know what to pick, go with commands first."?
